# Roteamento com slim não funciona

Tags: slim

Estou tentando usar o [Slim FrameWork](http://www.slimframework.com/) seguindo a [documentação](http://www.slimframework.com/development) para o mesmo, configurei o mod_rewrite e instalei o mcryp;

Se eu chamar `http://localhost/slim/books` tenho: Not Found

Se eu chamar `http://localhost/frame/index.php?books` funciona!

O que poderia ser isso.

Isso acontece para o [slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) e [flight](http://flightphp.com/), mas não acontece para o [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Aqui meu .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA]
```

Estou usando:

Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu 14.04)

PHP Version 5.5.15RC1

Alguem sabe o que poderia ser?

Comment: O endereço é localhost/slim ou /frame?

Answer (score 1):

Seu htaccess reescreve a URL sem repassar nenhum parâmetro. Tente isto:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: Amigo, infelizmente não funcionou!!

Answer (score 0):

Partindo do pressuposto que `/frame` é a *root URI* da sua aplicação — isto é, o local, relativo ao *document root* onde se encontra o arquivo `index.php` que inicializa a aplicação Slim — e que a regra de reescrita expressa no `.htaccess` é

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

a URL correta deve ser `http://localhost/frame/books`.